# Selecionar uma opção dentro do .realHover() usando Cypress

Tags: cypress

estou tentando selecionar as opções dentro de um "dropdown"
[elemento inspecionado](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J99s8.png)

unica forma que consegui para chegar ate ele é usando

cy.get('#menu-principal > :nth-child(1) > [href="javascript:;"]').realHover()

porem não consigo selecionar a opção Usuário
ja tentei o .select e fiz alguma tentativas com o xpath, mas sem sucesso

o ideia é saber como consigo fazer a seleção dentro do .realHover()

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia senhores

consegui resolver, vou deixar aqui caso alguém esteja iniciando como eu e tenha duvidas

cy.get('#menu-principal do dropdown').realHover().then(() => {
cy.get('a[href="/home"]').should('contain', 'conteúdo').click();
});

desta forma eu consegui interagir dentro do meu dropdown

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).